# Function it gives me position of letter in string (python)

Tags: python, function, indexing, position

I mean like it is gonna ask me to type some string and ask me to type one letter and gives me position of it.
like "Hello"
i wanna letter e
it gives me position 2.

Thank you for answer

Comment: use the built-in *find()* function and add 1 - i.e., "Hello".find('e') + 1 == 2

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I know of that you could use, one makes the string into a list, making it easier to iterate through, and the other just iterates through the string.

Option #1 (String):

```
string = 'Hello'

for char in string:
    if char == 'e':
        break <or whatever code you want here>
```

Option #2 (List):

```
def split(string):
    return [char for char in string]
 
string = 'Hello'
for char in split(string):
    if char == 'e':
        break <or your code>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .find method.

```
string = input() # Gets the input from the user
character = input() # Gets another input from the user (the character)
index = string.find(character) # This function is going to return the index of character in string
print(index + 1)
```

It prints index + 1 because the index in python (actually most languages) starts at 0

Input: 
Hello 
e

Output: 
2